# How to create reusable button component with vanilla js and sass?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, web-component

I have to make a reusable button component with vanilla js and scss, but I haven't done it yet. Can somebody explain how could I do it ?
I am new at this so I don't know where to look for it.

Update: Do I have to use javascript or can I use only HTML and SCSS/CSS for it?

Comment: Note that you're going to need to compile SCSS -> CSS as SCSS is a superset of CSS, not a thing on itself.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to do that. One simple solution is create the styles on css and toogle between the different subclasses , then, create a method o function to return this component with the values.

```
var cusButton =  (i_params )  => {
var curButton = document.createElement ('INPUT'), buttonContainer;
curButton.classList.add  (i_params.classname);
curButton.type = 'button';
curButton.value = i_params.valueButton;
//the classname has the properties that you have to create before...
buttonContainer = document.getElementById
(i_params.idButContainer);
buttonContainer.appenChild  (curButton);

}

//Then, create one object for each button and call this function to populate the DOM with the new buttons:

var propButton ={ classname : 'created-class', valueButton : 'Click here to sens', idButContainer : 'id-name-node'};

cusButton  (propButton );
```